# Using JayData to filter Header Detail Table - Inner Join SQL, oData

Tags: javascript, odata, jaydata, datajs

Hello Am kinda new and using JayData and oData so please forgive my ignorance.

This is my object structure :

```
$data.Entity.extend('PlannerModel.vMasterPlanner', {
    'Sequence_Number': { key:true,type:'Edm.Int32',nullable:false,required:true },
    'Scenario_Name': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:true,maxLength:250 },
    'Activity_ID': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:false,required:true,maxLength:250 },
    'Activity_Description': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:true,maxLength:500 },
    'Object_ID': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:true,maxLength:250 },
    'Object_Description': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:true,maxLength:400 },
    'Operation_Code': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:false,required:true,maxLength:250 },
    'Operation_Description': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:true,maxLength:50 },
    'Crew_ID': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:true,maxLength:250 },
    'Crew_Name': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:true,maxLength:50 },
    'Period': { type:'Edm.Int32',nullable:true },
    'vActivity': { type:'PlannerModel.vActivity',required:true,inverseProperty:'vMasterPlanners' }   });

 $data.Entity.extend('PlannerModel.vActivity', {
    'Activity_ID': { key:true,type:'Edm.String',nullable:false,computed:true },
    'Activity_Name': { type:'Edm.String',nullable:false,required:true },
    'vMasterPlanners': { type:'Array',elementType:'PlannerModel.vMasterPlanner',inverseProperty:'vActivity' }   });


$data.EntityContext.extend('PlannerServiceLibrary.PlannerEntities', {
    ProgressDetails: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: PlannerModel.ProgressDetails },
      ProgressHeaders: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: PlannerModel.ProgressHeader },
      vCrews: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: PlannerModel.vCrew },
      vPeriods: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: PlannerModel.vPeriod },
      vOperations: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: PlannerModel.vOperation },
      vActivities: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: PlannerModel.vActivity },
      vMasterPlanners: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: PlannerModel.vMasterPlanner }   });
```

Just a little explanation : 
 Table Master planner is a detail table and Table activity is the header table 
I need to select all the activities from the activity table (header) where the crew ID which is found in the detail table for example = 2
how can i do that using oData and JayData

am currently using

```
provider.vActivities.filter(function (ac) { 
return ac.vMasterPlanners.Crew_ID == "FM2_F/W" })
               .toArray(function (e) {
                   console.log(e);
               });
```

and this is the error Unknown expression type to handle: EntitySetExpression
 localhost/mobile-web/htdocs/assets/jayData/jaydata.js
Line 89

Please help anyone !!

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a known issue I have added it in to github http://github.com/jaydata/jaydata/issues/70

Answer (score 1):

You need 'some' or 'every' operator, see this http://jaydata.org/blog/using-some-and-every-with-jaydata-odata-provider

Comment: can you try to give me an example using the tables that i have provided? i already have seen this post and i didnt understand the way you call this variable subFilter again in the filter Thanks !!!!

Comment: Hi It should be something like this: var subFilter = provider.vMasterPlanner.filter(function(ac){return ac.Crew_ID == "FM2_F/W";}); provider.vActivities.filter(function (ac) { ac.vMasterPlanners.some(this.subfilter);},{subfilter:subfilter}).toArray(...

Comment: you only need 'some' or 'every' in this situation (1..n), 1..1 or n..1 does not require it. 'some' means that at least one record matches, every means all records must match

Comment: not solved yet :-/ i remembered that i already tried that and it gave me this error

Comment: 400 Bad Request
  15ms 
datajs-1.0.3.js (line 1074)

"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost/PlannerService/Planner.svc//vActivities?$filter=vMasterPlanners/any(ac:%20(ac/Crew_ID%20eq%20%27FM2_F/W%27))"
am afraid it has something to do with my service ?

  var subFilter = provider.vMasterPlanners.filter(function(ac){return ac.Crew_ID == "FM2_F/W";}); 
      provider.vActivities.filter(function (ac) { ac.vMasterPlanners.some(this.subfilter); }, { subfilter: subFilter }).toArray(function (e) { console.log(e);})

Comment: Try something simple first like provider.vActivities.toArray() to see that your service works

Comment: Also use our patched datajs. Try to catch the network traffic (request header and body) and the server log.

Comment: actually the service is working fine but when i reach this method boom an error!!

Comment: Ive upgraded to .net 4.5 and changed the Protocol to V3 the error changed to something like wcf The DataServiceVersion '2.0' is too low for the request. The lowest supported version is '3.0'."

Comment: and when i redowngraded i just received plain :{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An error occurred while processing this request."}}}

Comment: NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/PlannerServiceV3/PlannerService.svc//vActivities?$filter=vMasterPlanners/any(ac:%20(ac/Crew_ID%20eq%20%27FM2_F/W%27))"

Comment: Try to make it simpler. Try the subfilter alone like provider.vActivities.filter(....).toArray

Comment: I think your answer is correct however : I have done the following downloaded the oData northwind project from JayData and wrote the following query reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222134/inner-join-in-jaydata
and did the same query 
ordersQuery = northwind.Orders.filter( function(order) { return order.Value > 200 });

northwind.Customers.filter( function(customer) {
 return customer.Orders.some(ordersQuery);
}).toArray(function(e){ console.log(e)})

and same thing i had the same problem its driving me crazy!!

Comment: Did you open the issue on github?

Comment: I did https://github.com/jaydata/jaydata/issues/70

Thanks for the help and time man :)