# Jaydata Odata Unknown expression type to handle: EntitySetEx

Tags: odata, jaydata, datajs

I get this error: "Unknown expression type to handle: EntitySetExpression"
when trying to filter or order on an Odata navigation property.

```
    App.store.Person.include('Friend')
    .filter("it.age >= 10 && it.Friend.age >=10").toArray();
```

I get the same error if I include a navigation property in an order function:

```
App.store.Person.include('Friend').orderBy("it.Friend.age").toArray();
```

any idea as to why this shouldnt work?
thanks

EDIT:
My Question was a bit misleading! what I tried to to was filtering the navigation property itself in the same query. I was also wrong to think that JayData would return navigation properties as Queryable objects.

Comment: Include will be translated to $expand when you use odata. you can not do filter or orderby on $expand. It's a limitation of odata and not jaydata. Actually it'd be difficult in sql, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that Person and Friend is a 1-N relation so for the filter you'll need the some() or every() operation, see this: [Using JayData to filter Header Detail Table - Inner Join SQL, oData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081989/using-jaydata-to-filter-header-detail-table-inner-join-sql-odata)

For the orderby() I'm still looking

Comment: thanks @Gabor, I had seen this post but unfortunatly it doesnt actually return a filtered navigation property but rather the parent object wich has some or every items that match the predicate. Maybe I'm doing this wrong. would I have to create 2 separate queries. I sometimes forget JSQL is not LINQ!

Comment: this should work, please try: 


     var subquery = App.store.Friends.filter('it.age >= 10');
     App.store.Person.include('Friend')
     .filter("it.age >= 10 && it.Friend.some(this.subquery)", { subquery: subquery }).toArray();

Comment: please be aware that it returns all Person who is older then 10 and any of his friend is older then 10 but will return all his friends not only his friends older then 10!

Comment: Yes it does work! but not the way I expect I guess... this will give me all persons who have friends > 10 yo but it will still include friends < 10 yo in the navigation array. How should I go about this? I need to actually filter the content of the navigation property as well. I probably got something wrong... sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Thats it Gabor! your second comment is spot on! how would I then filter this subset?

Comment: You can not have a condition on include... You have two choices: 1. filter on the client side, it's really an easy one liner 2. change your filter to filter on Friend and not on Person, like Friend.filter('it.age > 10 and it.Person.age > 10').include('Person') but in this case the Friends won't be grouped by Person...

Comment: also, you can not do .orderBy("it.Friend.age"), you can sort it on client side, too

Comment: Thanks @Gabor, I endedUp filtering the array! Its a chame that we cannot actually return a Queryable from navigation properties! That would be awesome! thanks for your Help!

Comment: I saw your comment which was rejected by some editors (not me). You can not filter on navigation, odata can not do this